# git creating a branch from the master

Tags: git, git-branch

I am new to using git and come from SVN background. I have checkout a project containing all the files in the default master branch. All the files in the master branch are outdated and I need to checkin a new set of files. But I am planning to create a new branch for the same and continue my development in the branch.

1. Do I need to be in the master branch to create a new branch?
2. Command to create a new branch so that the master branch is untouched.
3. How to switch to the master/mybranch branch later.
4. Command to know which branch I am currently working on?

Please let me know as I do not want to screw up my existing master branch.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching

Comment: You need some git backgroud, please look the @dalen link and later, if you have some question you can create a new post here.

Answer (score 1):

1: I think you can be in whatever branch you want.

2: `git checkout -b newbranch`, this create and change to the new branch

3: `git checkout branchtoChange`

4: `git branch`

Also, take a look to the link @dalen post in the comment. Some time ago I created a [cheatSheet](http://elbauldelprogramador.com/mini-tutorial-y-chuleta-de-comandos-git/) of git based on that book, [Git scm](http://git-scm.com/book)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can be in any branch when creating a new branch. The point is, when you create a new branch, it will fork the new branch from your current branch only.
2. `git checkout -b newBranchName`
3. `git checkout branchNameToSwitch`
4. `git branch`. It will list all the branches in your local repository. Your current branch will be marked with `*` . You can also use `git branch -a` to list remote branches as well.

You can refer to this [GitHub forum](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches) as well for basic branching and merging concepts.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes if you need changes from master, you need to checkout in new branch from master.
2. You can create branch using two approaches

> ```
> git branch <branch name>
> git checkout <branch name>
> ```

OR

```
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

1. git checkout  makes you switch to different branches.
2. When you run git branch you will get all branch names with asterstik on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, if you wish to create a new branch from the master branch then you need to be in master branch. The point is, when you create a new branch **B** by being in any branch **A**, it will create the branch **B** with the contents you have updated to till date in branch **A**.

2) 
The command to create a new branch,

**git branch NewBranchName,**

**git checkout NewBranchName**

(or)

**git checkout -b NewBranchName** (It will create a new branch and checkout to the new branch in a single command)

Then push the new branch to the remote by the following command,

**git push origin master**

3)
**git checkout NewBranchName** (switches to NewBranchName branch when you are in any branch)

or

**git checkout master** (switches to master when you are in any branch)

4) 
**git branch**

The pointer * represents that, In which branch you are right now.

Comment: Use `git pull` before hand, when you are on the source branch, to make sure it's up to date, before you create your new branch.